Error: Cannot find module './types/identity' in Node.js with TypeScript
'm building a Node.js project using TypeScript, and I'm encountering an issue where the module ./types/identity cannot be found when I try to run my application. Here’s the setup:
Project Structure:
backend/
├── kids-service/
│   ├── src/
│   │   ├── index.ts
│   │   ├── router.ts
│   │   └── types/
│   │       └── identity.d.ts
├── auth-service/


Error:
When I start the server using nodemon, I get the following error:
Error: Cannot find module './types/identity'
Require stack:

/home/lenovo/backend/kids-service/src/index.ts
at Function.Module._resolveFilename.sharedData.moduleResolveFilenameHook.installedValue ...

Error: Cannot find module './types/identity'
Require stack:
- /home/lenovo/palmyra-backend/kids-service/src/index.ts
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename.sharedData.moduleResolveFilenameHook.installedValue ...


Code:
This is the relevant part of my src/index.ts file:
import express from 'express';
import http from 'http';
import bodyParser from 'body-parser';
import cookieParser from 'cookie-parser';
import compression from 'compression';
import cors from 'cors';
import mongoose from 'mongoose';
import router from './router';
import './types/identity'; // This line causes the error

const app = express();

app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(bodyParser.json());

const server = http.createServer(app);

server.listen(8081, () => {
    console.log('Kids service running on http://localhost:8081');
});


TypeScript Config (tsconfig.json):
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "ES6",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "strict": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "typeRoots": [
      "./node_modules/@types",
      "./src/types"
    ],
    "types": [
      "node",
      "express"
    ]
  },
  "include": [
    "src/**/*.ts",
    "src/types/**/*.d.ts"
  ]
}


identity.d.ts:
declare namespace Identity {
  interface User {
    id: string;
    name: string;
  }
}


What could be causing this error, and how can I resolve it? Is there something wrong with how I’m referencing the identity.d.ts file or the TypeScript configuration?

As the tsconfig.json file includes the directory containing identity.d.ts under
"typeRoots": ["./types", "./node_modules/@types"]

you can remove the line import './types/identity';
Also, src/types/**/*.d.ts in include is redundant.
Since src/**/*.ts already includes all .ts files (including .d.ts files in subdirectories), src/types/**/*.d.ts in include is unnecessary. You can simplify the include section as:
"include": [src/**/*.ts"],

